# How to Take user input under Brackets?

Tags: c++

The program must take the user input in brackets, How to achieve it?
The Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 cout << "Available options [-] [+] [*] [/]" << '\n';
 cout << "---------------------------------" << '\n';
 cout << " + " << '\n';
 cout << " - " << '\n';
 cout << " * " << '\n';
 cout << " / " << '\n';
 char cd_1;
 cout << "Choose One Option: [" << " " << "]";
 cin >> cd_1;
}
```

[image]

Comment: @churill yes this is what I want to move the cursor between the brackets when the user is asked to choose an option

Comment: @TedLyngmo Cool work like a Bitcoin

Comment: @Arnold-Baba  I know almost nothing about Bitcoins :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo :-) I can realize :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::cout << "Choose One Option: [ ]\b\b";
```

The `\b`s will backspace 2 steps, placing the cursor between `[` and `]`.

---

In the unlikely event that `\b` performs a destructive backspace on your target machine (which I don't think will ever happen), you have one more option:

```
std::cout << "                     ]\rChoose One Option: [";
```

Here the `\r` returns the cursor back to the beginning of the line (carriage return) and then the beginning of the line is printed, creating the same visual look as in the first version.

Comment: Beware, the `\b` may be destructive as well.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I haven't seen that ever - but i've only used ASCII backspace (where it does not erase).

Comment: @TedLyngmo Is it possible? to stop cursor erasing the bracket when The input is ++ instead of +

Comment: @Arnold-Baba In standard C++ you have very little/no control when you require user input. The user can input (and it'll be printed on screen) pretty much whatever the user likes and only after the user has pressed RETURN can you check what you got. If you need more control you need to use some platform specific code. There are libraries that can make it sort of portable (`curses`, `ncurses`, `pdcurses`, ...).